# iptables -P OUTPUT DROP loses SSH connection despite exception rule

Tags: debian, iptables

I would like to try a DROP default policy on OUTPUT.

I had added an exception to still serve my SSH connection:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

But the moment I change the default policy, I'm kicked out and need to restart the server to gain access again.

```
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

I even tried this before Dropping the Output and still the same issue.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: Do note that OpenSSH [used to have the `UseDNS` feature enabled by default](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html#6.8) where it attempts to lookup remote names via DNS.. if using that, you would additionally lock yourself out if your rules for tcp+udp port 53 are insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sport/dport parameters refer to (here: tcp) packets, not connections.

From the perspective of the *ssh server* the outgoing (OUTPUT) packets originate from port 22, but are unlikely sent to that same port on your *ssh client* machine.

Try this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

The destination port of those packets is very likely arbitrarily assigned some unused port (such as port 42123) on the client machine or its NAT gateways. Only that the packet leaves your server *from* the ssh port is known.